# How to SELECT multi-columns from a column?

Tags: mysql, join, select, query

I have a table with the structure

```
book_id int(11),
section_id int(11),
note_id int(11),
item_number int(11),
text varchar(255),
UNIQUE(book_id,section_id,note_id,item_number)
```

item_number can be 1 or 2 only.

How can I make a `SELECT query` to get text for item_number 1 and 2 together for each `book_id,section_id,note_id`

```
SELECT book_id, select_id, note_id, TEXT_number_1, TEXT_number_2

TEXT_number_1 = text (WHERE item_number=1)
TEXT_number_2 = text (WHERE item_number=2)
```

I considered two options:

1. GROUP BY, which can give me a CONCAT(TEXT_number_1,TEXT_number_2)
2. JOIN, which I am not sure what is the best query.

Comment: Question is unclear - where does `number_2` come from? I'm assuming `number_1` is `number INT (11)`? BTW, I would call `number INT(11)` something like `book_number INT(11)` as `NUMBER` is a [reserved word](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) - although perhaps not for MySQL (yet...)

Comment: @Vérace sorry about that. I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t0.book_id, t0.select_id, t0.note_id, t1.TEXT_number_1, t2.TEXT_number_2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT book_id, select_id, note_id
      FROM `table`) t0
LEFT JOIN `table` t1 ON t0.book_id=t1.book_id
                     AND t1.item_number=1   
                  /* AND t0.select_id=t1.select_id 
                     AND t0.note_id=t1.note_id */
LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t0.book_id=t2.book_id 
                     AND t2.item_number=2   
                  /* AND t0.select_id=t2.select_id 
                     AND t0.note_id=t2.note_id */
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but be sure to increase `group_concat_max_len`.